# Exporting React component to selectable text Pdf which can be downloaded

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, pdf-generation

I tried kendo pdfexport but this gives a blank space in pdf if I use google charts or other library charts. I tried react-pdf/renderer but that doesn't export existing components as it uses only View, Text, Image from @react-pdf/renderer. Converting html to image and to pdf will decrease the image quality  and the text is also not selectable.

I want to export React component into pdf with selectable text & can be downloaded. Please provide some suggestions or libraries or code snippets. Thanks in advance !!